# Creating a smooth game frame timer for WP7 SilverLight game

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, timer, game-engine

So I have been testing some new algorithms for creating a vertical scrolling game in silverlight. I came up with a very simple solution. However, when you run it on the phone there is a ton of inconsistencies in frame rates. I don't know if this is due to a poor algorithm, drawing to many things at once (only a png background and a stock player image at the moment) or something else.

Essentially what I want is a game loop timer that executes a method that I can execute all the update methods from and have a consistent look and feel regardless what part of the game you are at. Here is the back-end code.

```
   public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        int counter = 0;
        DispatcherTimer playerTimer;

        string _START   = "START";
        string _FALLING = "FALLING";
        string _LEFT    = "LEFT";
        string _RIGHT   = "RIGHT";
        string _CENTER  = "CENTER";

        string playerState = "";
        int playerMoveTimeout = 20;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            playerState = _START;

            playerTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            playerTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.00999);
            playerTimer.Tick += playerTimer_Tick;
            playerTimer.Start();
        }

        void playerTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updatePlayer();

            if (counter > 0)
            {
                counter = updateBG(counter);
            }
        }
        public void updatePlayer()
        {
            if (Canvas.GetLeft(Player) + Player.Width >= 480)
            {
                playerState = _LEFT;

            }
            else if (Canvas.GetLeft(Player) <= 0)
            {
                playerState = _RIGHT;
            }
            if(playerMoveTimeout <= 0)
            {
                playerState = _FALLING;
            }
            if (playerState.Equals(_START))
            { }
            else if (playerState.Equals(_FALLING))
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(Player, Canvas.GetTop(Player) + 30);
            }
            else if (playerState.Equals(_LEFT))
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(Player, Canvas.GetTop(Player) - 60);
                Canvas.SetLeft(Player, Canvas.GetLeft(Player) - 20);
                playerMoveTimeout--;
            }
            else if (playerState.Equals(_RIGHT))
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(Player, Canvas.GetTop(Player) - 60);
                Canvas.SetLeft(Player, Canvas.GetLeft(Player) + 20);
                playerMoveTimeout--;
            }
            else //CENTER
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(Player, Canvas.GetTop(Player) - 60);
                playerMoveTimeout--;
            }
        }

        public int updateBG(int time)
        {
            if (Canvas.GetTop(background) > 800)
                Canvas.SetTop(background, -2400);
            int x = time;
            Canvas.SetTop(background, Canvas.GetTop(background) + 60);
            x -= 40;
            return x;
        }


        private void Player_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {

            Point point = e.GetPosition(Player);
            double Y = point.Y;
            double X = point.X;
            if (X < 80)
            {
                counter = 400;
                playerMoveTimeout = 20;
                playerState = _RIGHT;

            }
            else if (X > 120)
            {
                counter = 400;
                playerMoveTimeout = 20;
                playerState = _LEFT;

            }
            else
            {
                counter = 400;
                playerMoveTimeout = 20;
                playerState = _CENTER;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is more of a work around than a new timer. The answer to my specific problem wasn't the algorithm. This one is actually the smoothest and smallest for home built game engine that I have ever made. The problem was that I was attempting to move a 480X2400 background image and it was bogging it down. So what I ended up doing was nesting a new canvas within the main one and naming it background. Then all the elements that I want to move in the background I place on there

Like this

```
<Canvas Name="background">
    <Image Name="cloud" Source="cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="192" Canvas.Top="268"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy1" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="-11" Canvas.Top="592"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy2" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="192" Canvas.Top="-474"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy3" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Top="-900"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy4" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="192" Canvas.Top="-1566"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy5" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="-78" Canvas.Top="-2280"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy6" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="192" Canvas.Top="-2766"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy7" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="-102" Canvas.Top="-3390"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy8" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Top="-3122"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy9" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="-113" Canvas.Top="-2798"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy10" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Top="-3864"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy11" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Top="-4290" Canvas.Left="-102"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy12" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Top="-4956"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy13" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="-180" Canvas.Top="-5670"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy14" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Top="-6156"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy15" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="-192" Canvas.Top="-7278"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy16" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Top="-7010"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy17" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="-203" Canvas.Top="-6686"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy18" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Top="-7752"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy19" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Top="-8178" Canvas.Left="-192"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy20" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Top="-8844"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy21" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Left="-270" Canvas.Top="-9558"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud_Copy22" Source="/cloud.png" Width="247" Height="158" Canvas.Top="-10044"/>
</Canvas>


<Image Name="Star"  Visibility="Collapsed" Source="star.png" Height="50" Width="50" />
<Image x:Name="Player" Source="star.png" Width="200" Height="200" Canvas.Left="117" Canvas.Top="403"/>
<Rectangle Name="TapBox" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="248" Stroke="Black" Width="301" Canvas.Left="68" Canvas.Top="403" Opacity="0" Tap="Rectangle_Tap_1"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="alt"/> 
</Canvas>
```

You can load tons and tons of things on this canvas without reduced performance from what I can see.

Then to update it here is my new game loop

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        DispatcherTimer gameTimer;

        string _START           = "START";
        string _FALLING         = "FALLING";
        string _LEFT            = "LEFT";
        string _RIGHT           = "RIGHT";
        string _CENTER          = "CENTER";
        string playerState      = "";

        int counter             = 0;
        int playerMoveTimeout   = 40;
        public int altitude { get; set; }

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            buildGameArea();
            alt.Text = altitude.ToString();
            playerState = _START;
            gameTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            gameTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(3333);
            gameTimer.Start();
            gameTimer.Tick+=gameTimer_Tick;

        }

        void gameTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            updatePlayer();
            updateGameElements();
        }

        public void buildGameArea()
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(cloud, -300);
        }
        public void reloadPlayer()
        {
            playerState = _START;
            playerMoveTimeout = 40;
            Canvas.SetTop(Player, 300);
            Canvas.SetLeft(Player, 200);
        }
        public void updatePlayer()
        {
            if (Canvas.GetTop(Player) > 800)
            {
                reloadPlayer();
            }


            if (Canvas.GetLeft(Player) + Player.Width >= 480)
            {
                playerState = _LEFT;

            }
            else if (Canvas.GetLeft(Player) <= 0)
            {
                playerState = _RIGHT;
            }

            if (playerMoveTimeout <= 0)
            {
                playerState = _FALLING;
            }


            if (playerState.Equals(_START))
            { }
            else if (playerState.Equals(_FALLING))
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(Player, Canvas.GetTop(Player) + 30);

            }
            else if (playerState.Equals(_LEFT))
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(Player, Canvas.GetTop(Player) - 40);
                Canvas.SetLeft(Player, Canvas.GetLeft(Player) - 20);
                playerMoveTimeout--;
            }
            else if (playerState.Equals(_RIGHT))
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(Player, Canvas.GetTop(Player) - 40);
                Canvas.SetLeft(Player, Canvas.GetLeft(Player) + 20);
                playerMoveTimeout--;

            }
            else //CENTER
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(Player, Canvas.GetTop(Player) - 40);
                playerMoveTimeout--;
            }
            TapBox.Margin = Player.Margin;
        }
        public void updateGameElements()
        {
            alt.Text = altitude.ToString();


            //This single conditional moves every single thing on the background canvas
            if (counter > 0)
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(background, Canvas.GetTop(background) + 20);
                counter -= 20;
            }
        }

        private void Rectangle_Tap_1(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Point point = e.GetPosition(Player);
            double Y = point.Y;
            double X = point.X;
            altitude += 100;
            if (X < 80)
            {
                counter = 400;
                playerMoveTimeout = 40;
                playerState = _RIGHT;

            }
            else if (X > 120)
            {
                counter = 400;
                playerMoveTimeout = 40;
                playerState = _LEFT;

            }
            else
            {
                counter = 400;
                playerMoveTimeout = 40;
                playerState = _CENTER;

            }
        }
    }
```

If you were to put this on your device you would see that there is a consistent frame rate from beginning to end regardless how much you have going on.

Hopefully my wasted day figuring this out helps someone in the future.

Once again this is for Silverlight game programming. No XNA here